# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage , but there is no UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode

I am lost now with apple's warning 
`ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage` 
saying that the submitted app contains UIWebView.

I have removed all UIWebview in the app, going as far as even removing it in comments. Search function in Xcode and in Finder show no result.

All pods have been brought to the latest version, and running

```
nm myapp | grep UIWeb
for framework in Frameworks/*.framework; do
  fname=$(basename $framework .framework)
  echo $fname
  nm $framework/$fname | grep UIWeb
done
```

nicely lists all frameworks as being clean.

So where else could a UIWebView be hiding?

Comment: Did you manage to find some solution? I also can't find it anywhere in project and still build gets rejected.

Comment: Meanwhile I found out that xib files can have UIWebView which grep can't find: they have a <webview tag! Also, Facebook integration caused a problem and UIWebview only showed when doing grep -r "UIWebView" * on the archive itself

Comment: I removed them from xibs also and was getting the warning. 
Updating pods, seems to solved it. I think Firebase was creating the issue. 6.23.0 seems to be OK.
Maybe try updating as many pods as possible to latest version.